# Passing arrays to a subroutine that prints each array separately

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I know that this is probably a simple fix, but I have not been able to find the answer through google and searching through the questions here.

My goal is to pass multiple arrays to a subroutine that simply iterates through each array separately and prints each array with something before and after it.

What I have:

```
@A1 = (1, 2, 3);
@A2 = (4, 5, 6);

printdata(@A1, @A2) ;

sub printdata {
   foreach(@_) {
      print "$_" ; 
      print "@@@"
      }
   }
```

What I am attempting to get is:

123@@@456@@@

Instead its treating both arrays as one and iterating through each variable in the array, Putting the separator after every variable vice the entire array.

1@@@2@@@3@@@etc.....

I am not sure how to get the subroutine to treat the arrays as separate rather than as one.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you've discovered is the List context in Perl.  Lists are what get passed to methods (and almost any time you do use a paren with commas inside).  They automatically flatten anything inside of them - arrays or hashes.  This can be really convenient when passing arguments to functions (eg, you can build up all the arguments in an array, then pass it as a list to the function) or collating data from multiple sources (such as combining multiple hashes or arrays), but this idea of 'context' is new to most programmers and so can trip people up. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the arrays as references:

```
@A1 = (1, 2, 3);
@A2 = (4, 5, 6);

printdata(\@A1, \@A2) ;

sub printdata {
   foreach(@_) {
      print @$_ ; 
      print "@@@"
      }
}
```

The sub call expands the arrays into a list of scalars, which is then passed to the sub within the `@_` variable. E.g.:

```
printdata(@A1, @A2);
```

is equal to:

```
printdata(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I knew I was missing something simple. I don't exactly understand references, but I will be researching it now.

Comment: Its not simple, by adding  "\"  he introduced a new concept of  perl programming  which is very different from your concept

Answer (score 5):

See the section on "[Pass by Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Pass-by-Reference)" in [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

Comment: But what about the fishers? ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$LIST_SEPARATOR>;

my @A1 = (1, 2, 3);
my @A2 = (4, 5, 6);
{   local $LIST_SEPARATOR = '';
    my @a = map { "@$_" } \@A1, \@A2;
    $LIST_SEPARATOR = '@@@';
    print "@a\n";
}
```

You also could have used `join` (po-tay-to, po-tah-to).

```
my @a = map { join( '', @$_ ) } \@A1, \@A2;
print join( '@@@', @a ), "\n";
```

Comment: I like the use of the somewhat obscure `continue`: `for (@_) { print @$_ } continue { print "@@@" }`

Comment: @TLP, Cool!. I have *never* used `continue`, it has always looked like an ugly tack-on--probably a bias coming from other languages. I might need to reconsider.

Comment: I've never used it either. ;) I just thought this was a fun opportunity to try it out. Easy mnemonic: It does the same as the third element in a c-style for loop, `for (init; inc; *continue*)`